# Dismissing presented view controller returns to root view of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, presentviewcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a stack of view controllers. Something like below:

```
    [RestListViewController, RestViewController, ProdListViewController]
```

`ProdListViewController` presents another view controller `ProdViewController`.

When I call

```
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am returned the the `RestListViewController`

I understand this is because the `UINavigationController` is released when the view controller is presented, therefore is reloaded.

Is there any way I can stop this happening and have the dismiss function return to the original vc stack?
Edit:
ProdViewController is presented as so

```
let productViewController = ProdViewController()
self.present(productViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and dismissed

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I think you may be mistaking the cause of the problem here – the UINavigationController is *not* released when a view controller is presented atop it. Perhaps the ProdListViewController is being presented instead of pushed? That might cause the symptoms you describe.

Comment: ProdListViewController is being pushed

Comment: You have to be doing something else to cause that behavior

Comment: How is prodviewcontroller presented and where are you calling self.dismiss?

Comment: To clarify, all of this functionality is within a UINavigationController that is within a TabBarItem. Looking at the view controller stack before and after pushing, I see the correct stack up until inside the presented view controller, where the navigation controller becomes nil?

Comment: @JohnD Added as an edit

Comment: do you dismiss inside ProdViewController or outside?

Comment: @JohnD inside ProdViewController